# Gradle custom plugin which needs to access sources

Tags: java, gradle, gradle-custom-plugin

I wrote a gradle plugin where I do expect to access sources of the project and generate some files. Everything works when I run my project from Java, however when I try to do the same via plugin it does not work. It does not see the sources of the project.

Is it true, that in gradle, sources are not visible to buildscript and therefore to plugin as well? Is it possible to make them available for the plugin?

This class is used to get the list of classes.

```
public class ClassFinder {
    private final List<? extends Class<?>> classes;

    public ClassFinder(String packageToScan) {
        ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider provider = new ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider(false);
        provider.addIncludeFilter(new RegexPatternTypeFilter(Pattern.compile(".*")));
        Set<BeanDefinition> classes = provider.findCandidateComponents(packageToScan);

        this.classes = classes.stream()
                .map(bean -> {
                    try {
                        return Class.forName(bean.getBeanClassName());
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
                    }
                })
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    ...
}
```

I can use it either in `main` method or in plugin. In `main` it finds all the classes in my current project. In plugin it does not find anything (except libraries).

Comment: Could you show some code of your plugin? What do you mean by '*Everything works when I run my project from Java*'?

Comment: ok I added the class which fails. I use Spring utilities there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are referring to are not *source files*, but already compiled classes on the current classpath. Since Gradle compiled those classes, it is clear that they cannot appear on the classpath of the Gradle runtime and its plugins. So it will be **impossible** to collect the classes of your production code from a Gradle plugin. However, it would be possible to use Gradle to invoke your functionality from Gradle by using an `JavaExec` task with the classes from the compilation task on the classpath.

Comment: Why would it be "impossible" to load the classes, once compiled? It may not be good idea, but it is certainly possible.

Comment: Maybe the term "impossible" seems a little bit to strong, as there actually is a way to load the classes dynamically once they are compiled. However, taking a look at the usual Gradle build, any plugin will be loaded **before** the compilation of the project sources, therefore the resulting classes cannot be loaded with the plugin in an easy way.